# ggplot combining two plots from different data.frames

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to combine two ggplots, from two different data.frames, into one plot. Below you will find the code. I want to combine plot 1&2 or plots 3&4.

```
df1 <- data.frame(p=c(10,8,7,3,2,6,7,8),
             v=c(100,300,150,400,450,250,150,400))
df2 <- data.frame(p=c(10,8,6,4), v=c(150,250,350,400))

plot1 <- qplot(df1$v, df1$p)
plot2 <- qplot(df2$v, df2$p, geom="step")

plot3 <- ggplot(df1, aes(v, p)) + geom_point()
plot4 <- ggplot(df2, aes(v, p)) + geom_step()
```

This must be very easy to do, but somehow I can't get it to work. Thanks for your time.

Comment: using `ggplot()` syntax, you can specify the data to use for each individual layer, e.g. `geom_step(data=df2)`

Answer (score 90, accepted):

As Baptiste said, you need to specify the data argument at the geom level.  Either

```
#df1 is the default dataset for all geoms
(plot1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(v, p)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_step(data = df2)
)
```

or

```
#No default; data explicitly specified for each geom
(plot2 <- ggplot(NULL, aes(v, p)) + 
      geom_point(data = df1) +
      geom_step(data = df2)
)
```

Comment: @naught101 The outermost parentheses are a trick to make the plot print in the same line as its assignment.  You can use this trick with other variables too. `(my_variable <- 1:5)` is a cleaner version of `my_variable <- 1:5; my_variable`.

Answer (score 79):

The only working solution for me, was to define the data object in the geom_line instead of the base object, ggplot.

Like this:

```
ggplot() + 
geom_line(data=Data1, aes(x=A, y=B), color='green') + 
geom_line(data=Data2, aes(x=C, y=D), color='red')
```

instead of

```
ggplot(data=Data1, aes(x=A, y=B), color='green') + 
geom_line() + 
geom_line(data=Data2, aes(x=C, y=D), color='red')
```

[More info here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggplot.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can take this trick to use only qplot. Use inner variable `$mapping`. You can even add colour= to your plots so this will be putted in mapping too, and then your plots combined with legend and colors automatically.

```
cpu_metric2 <- qplot(y=Y2,x=X1) 

cpu_metric1 <- qplot(y=Y1, 
                    x=X1, 
                    xlab="Time", ylab="%") 

combined_cpu_plot <- cpu_metric1 + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(mapping=cpu_metric2$mapping)+
  geom_line(mapping=cpu_metric2$mapping)
```

Comment: how can I put two colors using this approach?

Comment: @WagnerJorge try to read qplot docs and add colour when initializing cpu_metric2, like `qplot(y=..., x=..., colour=...)`, then add colour inside `geom_line(mapping..., colour=...)`