# plotting data.frames with different row numbers and same col names. How to add legend and titles?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I want to combine three data frames with different row numbers and same column names into the same plot. 
Below is the code I am using based on another stack overflow question >[ggplot combining two plots from different data.frames](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9109156/13215833)<

```
    df1 <- data.frame(dist=c(5,10,15,25,30,40,45,50), #8
                      r2=c(105,90,70,50,40,15,17,8))
    df2 <- data.frame(dist=c(5,10,15,25,30,40,45,50,55,60),#10
                      r2=c(100,80,60,40,30,25,15,10,5,3))
    df3 <- data.frame(dist=c(3,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,60),#12
                      r2=c(110,100,80,60,50,35,30,25,20,15,10,5))
      ggplot() +
      theme_bw() +
      geom_line(data = df1, aes(x = dist, y = r2), color = "red") +
      geom_line(data = df2, aes(x = dist, y = r2), color = "blue")+
      geom_line(data = df3, aes(x = dist, y = r2), color = "orange")
```

However, in those answers, there is not information about adding legends, title or adjusting axis.
Any advice to include information from those three data frames into the plot is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggplot2` really likes things in a "long" format, so let's combine the data, preserving the frame name in a sense. While I'm using `"df1"` the string to add to `df1` the frame, you can change the strings to whatever you want. Also arbitrary is the `"nm"` label, this might be more descriptive (but you need to be consistent with it in `aes`).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df1$nm <- "df1"
df2$nm <- "df2"
df3$nm <- "df3"

bind_rows(df1, df2, df3) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(dist, r2)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_line(aes(color = nm)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(df1 = "red", df2 = "blue", df3 = "orange"))
```

[image: ggplot]

Also, you can add the `color` aesthetic mapping to the original `ggplot` call, there's nothing special with adding it here. I just reduced your code to deal with this format of data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I could not figure out how to change colors for each data frame and at the same time showing legend. Each df is a population with previous defined colors (i.e df1 -> "orange", df2 -> "black", df3 -> "pink") . Thanks.

Comment: `scale_color_manual` lets you control the color for each group.