# R: Plotting Columns of Different Sizes on Same Graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization, data-manipulation

I am using the R programming language. I have two datasets:

The first dataset:

```
my_data_1 <- data.frame(read.table(header=TRUE,
row.names = 1,
text="

  height    weight    age
1  13.14600 2882.7709  49
2  12.65080 3183.7991  48
3  13.84154 3138.2280  48
4  15.25780 2786.5297  49
5  15.01213 3006.9687  50
6  14.37567 3286.9644  50
7  12.99385 2881.7667  51
8  15.38893 2916.1883  50
9  14.80093 2791.7292  49
10 15.40423 2427.7706  50
11 17.55129  630.8886  20
12 18.34758 1076.6810  19
13 16.37789 1778.5550  20
14 14.98782 1401.4328  17
15 17.40527  361.3323  20
16 16.53979  869.5829  21
17 16.61986 1712.1686  19
18 17.78508 1961.6090  20
19 16.83144 1043.5052  19
20 18.66166  360.3037  20
                      
"))
```

The second dataset:

```
prior_age = rnorm(100000, 50,5)
   prior_height = rnorm(100000, 17,1)
  prior_weight = rnorm(100000, 3000, 200)

my_data_2 = data.frame(prior_age, prior_height, prior_weight)
```

(Based on the answer from this post: [ggplot combining two plots from different data.frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109156/ggplot-combining-two-plots-from-different-data-frames)) I am trying to plot the "densities" of the height variables from both data sets on the same graph. However, both datasets differ in the number of rows.

I tried the following code in R:

```
    library(ggplot2)
   ggplot() + 
    geom_density(data=my_data1, aes(x=height), color='green') + 
    geom_density(data=my_data2, aes(x=prior_height), color='red')
```

But this produces the following error:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (20): x
```

Can someone please show me how to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: After add `_` in your `ggplot` code(I think it's typo) it works for me.

Comment: @ Park: thank you for your reply! I am not sure I understand exactly - where do I need to add the "_" in this code? thank you!

Comment: Maybe it occurs your problem or maybe not. I'm not sure but in `geom_density(...)` part, code you provide saying `data = my_data1` but data you made was `my_data_1`. `_` was missing...

Comment: oh ok! that fixed the problem! is there way to add a legend? *green = measurements, red = prior"?

Comment: May I change shape of data to add legend?

Comment: sure! Here is the code I am trying to use

Comment: ggplot() +   geom_density(data=my_data_1, aes(x=height), color='green') +  stat_density(aes(x=height, colour="green"), geom="line",position="identity") +  geom_density(data=my_data_2, aes(x=prior_height), color='red') + show_guide=FALSE)+ stat_density(aes(x=prior_height, colour='red'), geom="line",position="identity")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from code you provide, I didn't need to change shape of data. Just use `guides(... = guide_legend(title = ...))` and `scale_colour_discrete` to manually change the legend's components.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_density(data=my_data_1, aes(x=height), color='green') + 
  stat_density(data = my_data_1, aes(x=height, colour="red"), geom="line",position="identity") + 
  geom_density(data=my_data_2, aes(x=prior_height), color='red') + 
  stat_density(aes(x=prior_height, colour='green'), geom="line",position="identity") +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(title = "new title"),) +
  scale_colour_discrete(labels = c( "prior", "measurements"))
```

[image]

Comment: @ Park: Thank you for your answer! Is there a way to replace "new title" with "Legend"?

Comment: @stats555 Just change that `new title` text to whatever you want.